# Using JWT authorization in combination with X-Auth-Tokens in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, httpsession

I'm trying to setup Spring Boot 3 to use both authentication using JWT and HTTP sessions with X-Auth tokens. The goal is to use X-Auth tokens as primary authentication method, but users might authenticate using an external provider which grants a JWT access token.

I've successfully managed to create two different authorization endpoints, one at `/auth` using form based login and returns an X-Auth token, and one at `/authJwt`. JWT authorization is only enabled at `/authJwt` and all other endpoints are protected using X-Auth tokens.

Is it possible to enable generation of X-Auth tokens by authentication using a JWT? I've configured HTTP sessions to always be created, and a call to `/authJwt` returns an X-Auth token in the HTTP header. But the X-Auth token is not valid when trying to authenticate.

This is the security configuration which I'm using (I've removed some irrelevant parts):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    // Endpoints which will be public and not require authentication
    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/auth"
    };

    /**
     * Filter chain for authenticating using JWT tokens
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain oAuth2ResourceFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .securityMatcher("/authJwt")
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .requestCache().disable().exceptionHandling().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    /**
     * Filter chain for enabling authentication.
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .requestCache().disable().exceptionHandling().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/auth").usernameParameter("loginName").passwordParameter("loginPassword")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK))
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Return 401 on no session
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .logout();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

This is the configuration for the sessions:

```java
@Configuration()
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }
}
```

Can anyone point in the correct direction of exchanging JWT tokens for X-Auth tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had assumed I needed to use Spring Session, but it was easier to solve it without sessions. Instead I added a custom token store and token filters which manages authorization. The token store:

```java
@Component
public class TokenStore {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Authentication> authenticationCache 
       = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /**
     * Generates and registers authentication token.
     *
     * @param authentication The authentication used.
     * @return Generated authentication token.
     */
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        authenticationCache.put(token, authentication);
        return token;
    }

    /**
     * Returns authentication from authentication token.
     *
     * @param token The authentication token to check.
     * @return Authentication if token exists, otherwise null.
     */
    public Authentication getAuth(String token) {
        return authenticationCache.getOrDefault(token, null);
    }

    /**
     * Removes authentication token.
     *
     * @param token Authentication token.
     */
    public void removeAuth(String token) {
        authenticationCache.remove(token);
    }
}
```

Token filter which is added to the `SecurityFilterChain` to validate access tokens:

```java
@Component
public class TokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    public TokenFilter(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if an authentication token is valid and sets authentication.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authToken = request.getHeader(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN_NAME);
        if (authToken != null) {
            Authentication authentication = tokenStore.getAuth(authToken);
            if (authentication != null) {
                SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The tokens are genereated either on the success handler of the form login:

```java
private void successHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
   String token = tokenStore.generateToken(authentication);
   response.addHeader(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN_NAME, token);
}
```

Or in the endpoint for the `/authJwt` endpoint:

```java
/**
 * Exchanges a valid JWT to an access token.
 *
 * This endpoint is protected using the OAuth2 filter chain.
 */
@PostMapping(value = "/authJwt")
public void verifyClient(HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
   String token = tokenStore.generateToken(authentication);
   response.addHeader(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN_NAME, token);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a custom authentication filter for the JWT token which would authenticate the user using the JWT token and then create an X-Auth token for the authenticated user.

1. Custom JWT auth filter:

```java
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/authJwt");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        // JWT authentication logic

        return null; // return the authenticated user
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Generate X-Auth token for the authenticated user
        String xAuthToken = "GENERATED_X_AUTH_TOKEN";
        response.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", xAuthToken);

        // Continue processing the request
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

2. Register the custom filter in your `WebSecurityConfiguration` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain oAuth2ResourceFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .securityMatcher("/authJwt")
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .requestCache().disable().exceptionHandling().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Now, when a user sends a request with a valid JWT token to the `/authJwt` endpoint, the filter authenticates the user using the JWT token, generates an X-Auth token and returns it in the `X-Auth-Token` header.

Comment: Thanks! We will try your solution and report if it works for us.

Comment: Your solution looks like it should work but we haven't had time to try it yet. I'll give you the bounty, and we'll accept when we have verified. Thanks for the suggestion, anyway!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I managed to figure it out without using sessions and posted my solution here as well. This solution seems to also be working, but would probably require some more configuration to make the tokens valid when using Spring Sessions.